# Address array with return value of enum

Tags: c++, arrays, enums

This is my problem:
I´ve defined some values:

```
enum HarmCons
{
  val1 = 0,
  val2 = 2,
  val3 = 4,
  val4 = 6
};
```

and I have an array

```
int foo [7] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 1222, 34, 5};
```

which I read in from an input file. I also have this:

```
char types[15] = "val1,val3,val4";
```

Now I would like to seperate the string by commata and address (in a loop) the entries in `foo`. So the first part of the string would be `val1` and it should return `16`.
I tried `foo[val1]`
which works fine. The problem is that by separating the string, I will always get a string or something and I cannot address an array by a string.
Is there any possibility to separate the string in a way I can use the result to address the array?

Comment: Are the names always sequential like `val1,val2,val3` or could they have gaps or not be sorted or not follow such a fixed pattern?

Comment: There are no reflection in C++ for string to enum, you may look at library as [better-enums](https://github.com/aantron/better-enums) to help on that part.

Comment: There are 13 possible names, it´s not a fixed number of names and they are not ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to use a hammer to drive a screw. Array is a nice data structure but doesn't fit all problems.

> will always get a string or something and I cannot address an array by a string

Indeed, you cannot. So you need something other than an array. It seems that you have a mapping from string to in integer value. A data structure for such mapping is... a map (also known as associative array, dictionary, ...)

The standard library has an implementation for you: `std::map<std::string, int>`. Depending on your use case, you may want to replace either the enum, or the array with the map.

Comment: Indeed, getting rid of the enum and using a map directly solves this without any hassle. +1

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to approach it.

Some notes:

1. converter function implemented in terms of specialised functor.
2. logic expressed in terms of small functions.
3. comments inline

-

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

// general concept of value conversion
template<class From, class To>
struct converter;

// helper function to select correct converter class
template<class To, class From>
To convert(From&& from)
{
    return converter<std::decay_t<From>, To>()(std::forward<From>(from));
};

enum HarmCons
{
    val1 = 0,
    val2 = 2,
    val3 = 4,
    val4 = 6
};

// specialise for converting from string to our enum
template<>
struct converter<std::string, HarmCons>
{
    HarmCons operator()(std::string in) const {
        using namespace std::literals;
        std::transform(std::begin(in), std::end(in), std::begin(in), [](auto&& c) { return std::tolower(c); });
        if (in == "val1") return HarmCons ::val1;
        if (in == "val2") return HarmCons ::val2;
        if (in == "val3") return HarmCons ::val3;
        if (in == "val4") return HarmCons ::val4;
        throw std::invalid_argument("out of range: "s + in);
    }
};

// helper functions
template<class Sequence, class F>
void for_each_comma(Sequence&& seq, F&& f)
{
    std::istringstream splitter(std::forward<Sequence>(seq));
    std::string name;
    while(std::getline(splitter, name, ','))
    {
        f(name);
    }
};

std::vector<int> read_int_array(std::istream& is)
{
    std::vector<int> values;
    int N;
    is >> N;
    values.resize(N);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < N ; ++i) {
        is >> values[i];
    }
    return values;
}

std::string dequoted_string(std::istream& is)
{
    std::string result;
    is >> std::quoted(result);
    return result;
}

// test against any istream
void test(std::istream& input)
{
    // read in test data
    input.exceptions(std::ios_base::badbit);
    auto values = read_int_array(input);

    // read in comma- delimted string
    auto value_names = dequoted_string(input);

    // perform conversion and lookup
    for_each_comma(value_names, [&](auto&& name){
        auto cons = convert<HarmCons>(name);
        std::cout << values.at(cons) << '\n';
    });
}

// our test
int main()
{

    std::istringstream testinput(R"__(
7
16 2 77 40 1222 34 5
"val1,val3,val4"
)__");

    test(testinput);
}
```

expected output:

```
16
1222
5
```

Answer (score -1):

If you truly wish to split the strings you can do so and simply compare the last characters to numbers described as chars.
Sort of like this:

```
If ( char1 == '1')
    Then set a int var to 1
```

And with a loop to do the same sort of thing but with increasing number of 0 for the tens, hundreds, and so on adding as you go.
Then you can use that int var to access the array.
However a switch case would probably be a better way to implement it than if statements.